# PL SQL procedure to print all materialized views giving error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a simple procedure that lists all the materialized views from the system and prints the status of those views in a tabular format.

When I execute the below procedure, it gives me error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with        << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Code:

create or replace PROCEDURE mview_status(

status    OUT VARCHAR2,

view_name OUT VARCHAR2

)

AS BEGIN

```
-- Create a temporary table to hold the results          

CREATE TABLE mview_bkp

(

    view_name VARCHAR(255),

    status VARCHAR(30)

);     -- Insert data into the temporary table by querying the all_mviews view

INSERT INTO mview_bkp

SELECT

    mview_name,

    compile_state

FROM sys.all_mviews;     -- Print the results in a table format

SELECT

    view_name,

    IF compile_state = 'VALID' THEN status := 'Valid';

    ELSE status := 'Invalid';

    END IF;

FROM mview_bkp;     -- Drop the temporary table

DROP TABLE mview_bkp; END;
```

Any help on how the above error can be resolved? TIA

Comment: You can't do DDL in static SQL in a procedure.  You can use dynamic SQL but you almost certainly should not-- dropping and creating tables at runtime in Oracle is very much a last resort.  A `SELECT` statement has to either have an `INTO` clause or be used to open a cursor.  You have two naked `SELECT` statements, neither of which would work.  Your procedure is declared with two scalar `OUT` parameters but that doesn't make sense if you may have multiple materialized views.

Comment: In theory, you could write a simple query, loop over the rows, and use `dbms_output` to print to the output buffer the client may (or may not) have allocated to display tabular results.  Whether that is actually helpful, though, depends a lot on the business problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Agreed, this is best done with a simple normal SQL query. And the code above is invalid because the IF THEN END IF block is PL/SQL and it's being mixed in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

This would at least be valid syntax.  The output may not be pretty (and I'm assuming no MV with a name longer than 30 characters-- if you have extended identifiers enabled that may not be a valid assumption).  If this is something you expect to run interactively via `SQL*Plus` or some other IDE, this may be sufficient assuming you enable `dbms_output`.  But it isn't appropriate if you are trying to return information to a client application.

```
BEGIN
  FOR mv IN (SELECT mview_name,
                    compile_state
               FROM sys.all_mviews)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( rpad(mv.mview_name,30,' ') || ' ' || 
                          (case mv.compile_state
                                when 'VALID' then 'Valid'
                                else 'Invalid' 
                            end) );
  END LOOP;
END;
```